# WickedPdf and Rails 5.1.4: can't instantiate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, wicked-pdf

I want to generate a PDF in a ruby service used by a Rails 5.1.4 app. It fails kind of quickly.

```
class PdfRenderer
  require 'wicked_pdf'

  def self.generate
    WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('<h1>Hello There!</h1>')
  end
end
```

When I call `PdfRenderer.generate` in my rspec tests, I get that error:

```
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `pdf_from_string' for nil:NilClass
```

I can't instantiate the WickedPdf class. When I call `WickedPdf.new` in byebug, I get `nil`.

The stacktrace:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `pdf_from_string' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/services/pdf_renderer.rb:25:in `generate'
 # ./spec/services/pdf_renderer_spec.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:201:in `block in serve'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `serve'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
 # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: There's a very easy way to test your theory: What happens if you write `WickedPdf.new`? Do you get `nil`? Either way, can I see a **full** stack trace please.

Comment: @TomLord question updated.

Comment: Well that's very strange... Have you done some weird stubbing in your test? Can you show the `rspec` file? Does `WickedPdf.new` return `nil` in the rails console, or only from this test?

Comment: show us the spec

Comment: You are both right, it was a stub mistake in my spec. I forgot the 'and_return' after my mock. I created that nil myself T_T